# Is this the correct way to make Laravel token middleware

Tags: laravel

I want to make my API unavailable to every client who doesn't have the token to access.

This means the Android app will send a `client` as `android` and `token` as `token string` in the header with keys `client` and `token`.

Now in `middleware`, I am checking it with my table fields to pass through authorization. If both matches then I will authorize and if don't then will send `403` response.

> I am aware of Passport but it is not what I am looking for. In fact,
>   consider it as a first layer of security and then use Passport as a
>   second layer of security to authorize the API

## Is this code is correct?

As I am not so familiar with `Laravel - Middleware` I just want to get some feedback from experts whether the code I have written is accurate and up to the standard. If not, I would appreciate your suggestion and help to make it better.

#### Middleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\ApiToken;
use Closure;
use function response;

class ApiAccess
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle( $request, Closure $next ) {

        if ( $this->checkToken( $request ) ) {
            return $next( $request );
        }

        return response()->json( [ 'error' => 'Unauthorized' ], 403 );


    }

    public function checkToken( $request ) {

        $client = $request->header( 'client' );
        $token  = $request->header( 'token' );

        $checkToken = ApiToken::where( 'client', $client )
                              ->where( 'token', $token )->first();

        return $checkToken;
    }
}
```

### API Route

***I am fetching result from the ApiToken table just to check.***

```
Route::get('/', function(Request $request) {
    return ApiToken::all();
})->middleware('apiAccess');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't add comment so writing here. It seems right to me but I don't think the extra layer is needed. Maybe your requirement needs it. Anyways, you can improve the checkToken function to return boolean value. Here it is:

```
public function checkToken( $request ) {

    $client = $request->header( 'client' );
    $token  = $request->header( 'token' );

    return ApiToken::where( 'client', $client )
                          ->where( 'token', $token )->exists();
// Nicer, and it will return true and false based on the existence of the token and client.
}
```

One more thing, status code 403 is returned when the access is forbidden. 401 is returned with unauthorised error.

Comment: It is well optimized and perfect query. Thanks a lot.